# Conditionally Apply Class with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF PRO) to build out a CMS for a client. Currently, ACF allows you to give a particular field a class. In addition, you can make this field appear under certain conditions.

I'm looking for a way to combine the these two concepts.

Simply put, let's say I want to have a text editor's background color turn blue if a certain condition is met. With the current set up, I'd have to create two completely different fields, a default field and a field that has its own class that I can target and make blue. This would mean that, if I started typing out my content and decided halfway through that I would rather a blue background, the content would appear to disappear because a completely new field would have to load based on the new condition.

I'd much rather be able to conditionally apply a class to a single field.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you wanting the condition to appear on the back end (i.e. your text editor example) or on the front end (for visitors)?

Comment: @WebElaine I am looking for this condition to appear on the text editor in the back end.